# Form action refreshes the page

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, href

I am experiencing trouble with the action attribute from Form. When I submit my form data the page gets reloaded.

```
<form name="circuitForm" action="#idchart" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitCircuit()" novalidate>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="circuitForm.$invalid" >Run</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, on my Form action I refer is on the same page.

```
<div ng-show="isValidData()">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-graphLabel" id="idchart">
        <h2>{{circuit.classe}} Chart</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-Graph">
    </div>
</div>
```

I only show this second page content when the form data is valid but when I click the run button the page gets reloaded and I lose all the input data.
Help me please...

Comment: can you show `submitCircuit` function code ?

Comment: There is:
    $scope.submitCircuit = function () {
        validData = true;
 $scope.circuit.classe = "Chart Title"
    }